# PHP not returning data from form

Tags: php

this is going to drive me mad, because its probably something I have missed but I have a form that the user selects a country and a league name, and returns a table of the found results.

The problem I am having is that if that search form is submitted it returns nothing, but if I just refresh the page as normal with no submit it works fine and returns all the results. As you can see below it sets the $subleaguesearch and $countrysearch variables if the form has not been submitted and thats working fine, its just when it has been submitted that is not, and I just can't seem to find why. Any help would be great! thanks.

p.s I am receiving no error message its just not returning anything at all. And I have echoed the variables back to screen after the form submittion and they echoed back with the correct values so I know the variables are being set ok!.

```
       <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <table id="searchsubleaguetable" width="670px" align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">    
                    <tr colspan="2">
                    <th colspan="2" align="left"><label>SEARCH SUBLEAGUES</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td align="right"><label>COUNTRY&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left"><SELECT NAME="country" style="font-size:12px; padding:4px;"><OPTION VALUE="0">All Countries<?php echo $options;?></option></SELECT></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td align="right"><label>SEARCH&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left"><input class="searchinputs" type="text" name="subleaguesearch" size="40" value=""></label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr width="100%" height="20px" colspan="2">
                    <td align="right"><label></td>
                    <td align="left"><input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Search" name="searchsubnow"></label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>




      if (isset($_POST['searchsubnow'])){
           $subleaguesearch = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
           $countrysearch = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subleaguesearch']);        
           if($countrysearch == 0){
           $countrysearch = "%%";
           }
        }else{
           $subleaguesearch = "";
           $countrysearch = "%%";
        }

        $rowsPerPage = 15;
        $pageNum = 1;

        if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $chosenpage = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
            $pageNum = $chosenpage;
        }

        $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

        $result = mysql_query(" SELECT s.league_id, s.leaguename, s.private, s.date, u.flag, u.firstname, u.country,
                                COALESCE(SUM(r.total_points),0) as totalpoints,
                                count(m.member_id) participants
                                from sub_leagues s
                                Left Join members_leagues m
                                On m.league_id = s.league_id  
                                Left Join member_results r
                                On r.member_id = m.member_id
                                join members u
                                on s.admin = u.member_id
                                WHERE u.country LIKE '$countrysearch'
                                AND s.leaguename LIKE '$subleaguesearch%'
                                Group By s.league_id
                                Order By r.total_points DESC, participants DESC, s.date ASC " . " LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage") 
                        or die ("<br/>&nbsp;Error - could not display league");
```

Comment: can we see the form? when you say refresh, do you mean refreshing after having submitted the form in the previous request?

Comment: Could you add the HTML form, so we can see how they fit together?

Comment: when I say refresh I mean just load the page as normal with no submittion by the form.

Comment: also, may help to print_r your $_POST array to see what is happening there.

Comment: When you say refresh, do you refresh after you try hitting submit? in other words the URL as the GET variables still in it? Also You know you are using a $_GET and $_POST in your code.

Comment: and the thing is I know that the variables are being set ok because I echoed the variables back after the form had been submitted and they was fine! which is why I am a tad confused.

Comment: You will need to do some debugging.  Is the returned result set empty?
Echo out your variables to ensure they all have the correct values.  Add descriptive echoes to each if block to ensure you are following the correct logic path.

Comment: ypu load page means you set $_GET[page] variable..right???If that is the case then you should put action of your form as url wid &page="page_value"..

Comment: The $_GET is irrelevant to this matter as Its for the pagination of the results.

Comment: it's because you assigned the wrong post variables to the wrong search variables. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagining you problem is in this code:

```
$subleaguesearch = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
$countrysearch = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subleaguesearch']);        
if($countrysearch == 0){
   $countrysearch = "%%";
}
```

First, you should check and make sure that $_POST['country'] and $_POST['subleaguesearch'] contain what you think they contain. If they do not, then you named the field in your form wrong most likely.

Second, it seems that you have assigned the wrong post fields to the wrong search variables. Notice $subleaguessearch = $_POST['country'] instead of equaling $_POST['subleaguesearch']. same with $countrysearch. So instead it should be something like:

```
$subleaguesearch = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subleaguesearch ']);
$countrysearch = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
```

Comment: Ah my god, haha Sometimes you just need that fresh pair of eyes to see it for you!. Thanks a lot! what a waste of everyones time...sorry!!.